# MySQL Query for HTML table using filters, COUNT, GROUP BY / LIMIT / ORDER BY and sub-queries

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I got a query that blows my head off for about 2 days, and I need some help. Pleeeaaze !

What I need to do is get data form described tables below and the output must display every message for each application using filters on customer.(name, codeX/Y/Z), application.(name, wave), migrationLabel.label, migrationMessage.(dates) using pagination (50 per pages).

Each application can display 0 to n messages and I have to make an HTML table using attribute "rowspan".

Here are the tables :

"# : PK"

"@ : FK"

- application(#id, label, @customerId)
- customer(#id, name, codeX, codeY, codeZ)
- erpApplication(#id, label, @customerId)
- migrationMessage(@applicationId, creationTime, closureDate, previsionalDate, @labelId, @authorId)
- migrationLabel(#id, label, ordering)
- works(@employeeId, @applicationId, @roleId)
- employee(#id, username)

Here is the current Query :

```
<?php
$query = 'SELECT 
        c.id AS customerId, c.name AS customerName, c.X3Code, c.mfgProCode, c.as400Code, c.jdeCode,
        a.id AS appId, a.label AS appName, a.wave,
        mm.closureDate, mm.previsionalDate, mm.content,
        ml.id, ml.label,
        q.msgCount
        FROM (
            SELECT a.id
            FROM `application` a
            JOIN `customer` c ON c.id = a.customerId
            ORDER BY c.name
        ) l
        JOIN application a ON a.id = l.id
        JOIN `customer` c ON c.id = a.customerId
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT applicationId, COUNT(*) AS msgCount
            FROM application a
            JOIN migrationMessage mm ON mm.applicationId = a.id
            JOIN migrationLabel ml ON ml.id = mm.labelId
            JOIN customer c ON c.id = a.customerId
            ' . $where . '
            GROUP BY applicationId
            LIMIT ' . $limit . ' OFFSET ' . $offset . '
        ) q ON q.applicationId = a.id
        LEFT JOIN `migrationMessage`mm ON mm.applicationId = q.applicationId
        LEFT JOIN `migrationLabel` ml ON ml.id = mm.labelId
        JOIN `works` w ON w.applicationId = a.id '
        . ($user->isOperator() ? ' AND w.roleId = ' . Role::Rri : ' AND w.employeeId = ' . $user->id)
    . ' JOIN employee e ON e.id = w.employeeId'
        . ($user->isJustUser() ? ' AND e.siteId = ' . $user->siteId : '')
        . $where
        . ' ORDER BY c.name, a.label, ml.ordering'
        . 'LIMIT ' . $limit . ' OFFSET ' . $offset;
```

Almost everything works using this query, the problem happens when I got an application with several messages which get itself on 2 pages...
For example, "rowspan" (msgCount in the query) is 5 but the 3 last messages are on a different page than the first 2 and then the HTML display is completely erroneous. [See HTML result](https://jsfiddle.net/ufakygmb/)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote my query from scratch and come with a result that completely fit my needs.

For those who wondered, the key is the RIGHT JOIN'ed query :

```
<?php
$query = 'SELECT
        c.id AS customerId, c.name AS customerName, c.X3Code, c.mfgProCode, c.as400Code, c.jdeCode,
        a.id AS appId, a.label AS appName, a.wave,
        mm.closureDate, mm.previsionalDate, mm.content,
        ml.id, ml.label,
        q0.msgCount
        FROM application a
        JOIN customer c ON c.id = a.customerId
        LEFT JOIN migrationMessage mm ON mm.applicationId = a.id
        LEFT JOIN migrationLabel ml ON ml.id = mm.labelId
        JOIN `works` w ON w.applicationId = a.id '
        . ($user->isOperator() ? ' AND w.roleId = ' . Role::Rri : ' AND w.employeeId = ' . $user->id)
    . ' JOIN employee e ON e.id = w.employeeId'
        . ($user->isJustUser() ? ' AND e.siteId = ' . $user->siteId : '')

    . ' LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT applicationId, COUNT(*) AS msgCount
        FROM application a
        JOIN migrationMessage mm ON mm.applicationId = a.id
        JOIN migrationLabel ml ON ml.id = mm.labelId
        JOIN customer c ON c.id = a.customerId
        GROUP BY applicationId
    ) q0 ON q0.applicationId = a.id
    RIGHT JOIN (
        SELECT a.id
        FROM application a
        JOIN customer c ON c.id = a.customerId
        LEFT JOIN migrationMessage mm ON mm.applicationId = a.id
        LEFT JOIN migrationLabel ml ON ml.id = mm.labelId
        ' . $where . '
        GROUP BY a.id
        ORDER BY c.name, a.label, ml.ordering
        LIMIT ' . $limit . ' OFFSET ' . $offset . '
    ) q1 ON q1.id = a.id
    ORDER BY c.name, a.label, ml.ordering'
```